# Not able to read the excel file on server

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to read the file with the given url ,for that i am using npm-xlsx module.Here is what I have done but i am getting an error when i try to read file on server but on local it works fine.

```
var XLSX = require('xlsx');
var workbook = XLSX.readFile('https://cdn.fbsbx.com/v/t59.2708-21/19148065_1524749367569037_4309051515965800448_n.xlsx/A-101.xlsx?oh=1ff8a1d77ee7c6ee08dabbf6a328cee1&oe=59413FB9');

console.log("workbook",workbook);
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: You get an error. What error?

Comment: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'https://cdn.fbsbx.com/v/t59.2708-21/19148065_1524749367569037_4309051515965800448_n.xlsx/A-101.xlsx?oh=1ff8a1d77ee7c6ee08dabbf6a328cee1&oe=59413FB9'

Comment: people who are downvoting atleast provide me an solution,why it is not working.

Comment: @ShantanuMadane — People who think a question is bad enough to downvote often either think it can't be answered or isn't worth answering. Try improving your question instead of complaining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`readFile` expects to be given a file path so it can read a file, it does not expect to be given an HTTP(S) URL so it can read an HTTP resource.

Download the data using your HTTP client library of choice. Then parse it with the `read` method.